# How can I fix segmentation fault in strcat function?

Tags: c, struct, function-pointers

I am trying to use function pointers as a member of a C struct.I have Identity,Person and RandomPeople types.My program ends with "program has stopped working". I debugged my program with gdb and I have the following output.

```
[New Thread 18028.0x2c28]
[New Thread 18028.0x4150]
enter the number of people:2
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x754c5619 in strcat () from C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\msvcrt.dll
```

(probably `strcat` in **RandomPeople.h**)

Here is my program:
`Identity struct` can create an identification number and check the given identification number.

**Identity.h** file:

```
#ifndef Identity_H
#define Identity_H
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

struct IDNO {
    char *(*CreateIDNo)(struct IDNO *);   
};

typedef struct IDNO *Id;
Id CreateID();
char *CreateIDNo(Id this);
#endif
```

**Identity.c** file:

```
#include "Identity.h"

char *CreateIDNo(Id this) { 
    int str[11]; 
    int totalodd = 0;
    int totaleven = 0;
    this->id = "";

    for (int i = 1; i < 12; i++) {           
        if (i == 1) {
            int n = 1 + rand() % 9;
            totalodd += n;
            str[i - 1] = n;
            continue;
        } else
        if (i != 1 && i % 2 == 0 && i < 10) {
            int n = rand() % 10;
            totaleven += n;
            str[i - 1] = n;
            continue;
        } else
        if (i != 1 && i % 2 != 0 && i < 10) {
            int n = rand() %10;
            totalodd += n;
            str[i - 1] = n;
            continue;
        } else
        if (i == 10) {
            int n11 = (7 * totalodd - totaleven) % 10;
            str[i - 1] = n11;
            continue;
        } else
        if (i == 11) {
            int n12 = (totalodd + totaleven + str[9]) % 10;
            str[i - 1] = n12;
            continue;
        }      
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < 11; i++) {
        char *b; 
        itoa(str[i], b, 10);
        strcat(this->id, b);
    }
    return this->id;
}
```

Each `Person` has `Identity` reference that can create identity numbers with using this reference.

**Person.h** file:

```
#ifndef PERSON_H
#define PERSON_H
#include "Identity.h"

struct PERSON {
    Id superid;
};

typedef struct PERSON *Person;
Person CreatePerson();
#endif
```

**Person.c** file:

```
#include "Person.h"

Person CreatePerson() {
    Person this;
    this = (Person)malloc(sizeof(struct PERSON));
    this->superid = CreateID();  //Creating my reference    
    return this;
}
```

**RandomPeople.c** file:

```
#include "RandomPeople.h"

void CreateRandomPeopleData(RandomPeople k) {
    Person person = CreatePerson();
    char *formatted_identity = person->superid->CreateIDNo(person->superid);
    strcat(data, formatted_identity);       
}
```

**test.c** file

```
int main() {
    RandomPeople rastgelekisiler = CreateRandomPeople();
    rastgelekisiler->CreateRandomPeopleData(rastgelekisiler);
    return 0;
}
```

Edit: I put these structs on my question because the segmentation problem probably arises in these function pointer bodies. These functions may return char pointer that may point wrong location or null. I think that this question has Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example. I am not desired to being downvoted.

Comment: That's not what I call a [**Minimal**, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Please try to narrow down the code to the smallest part that still exhibits your problem. And remember that pointers need to actually point somewhere where you can write data if you want to use them as destination in a `strcat` call.

Comment: Oh, and what is `scanf("%s", ...)` expecting for input? What is the variable `input`? Do the `"%s"` format and `input` match?

Comment: Thanks.I put these structs on my question because the segmentation problem probably arise in these function pointer bodies.(I gather random data(char pointer) from these function pointers.)

Comment: Four possibilities: (1) you are calling `strcat(a, b)` where either `a` or `b` is a null pointer; (2) you are calling `strcat(a, b)` where either `a` or `b` is a garbage value (not pointing anywhere); (3) `b` points to characters which are not a proper null-terminated string; (4) `a` points to a memory region which is not big enough to hold the concatenated string.  (4 is less likely in this case.)

Comment: Please read the page about "debugging small programs" linked at the bottom of [mcve]. Also, please think about the word **"minimal"** in [mcve].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You initialize `this->id` in **Identity.c** this way: `this->id = "";`

`strcat(this->id, b)` will try and fail to write to read only storage for the string literal `""`.

Incidentally, `b` is uninitialized when passed to `itoa(str[i], b, 10);` which is another count of undefined behavior.

Comment: Thanks a lot, Why I can't pass uninitialized char pointer into itoa() function?

Comment: @3code: no, you must pass a pointer to an array large enough to receive the converted value of the first argument as a C string, including the null terminator.

Comment: @3code: also work on your presentation: the code was badly misindented. Look at how I reformatted your post to make it readable.  It is also considered bad style and highly error prone to hide pointers behind typedefs. You do not seem to master the concepts of pointers and arrays, study that with a fellow, it is difficult but mandatory to write C code correctly. Finally, avoid using C++ keywords such as `this` as variable names, it is confusing for the readers.

Comment: 'char* b ;  malloc(sizeof(char) * (12));itoa (str[i],b,10);' I initialize b with this way.How can I initialize b with NULL terminator?

Comment: @3code: `itoa` sets the null terminator at the end of the string it constructs. After the `itoa()` call, you can store `b` to `this->id` with `this->id = b;`